# Changing background of ion-content ionic 4 not the inside elements

Tags: ionic-framework

I know there are already similar questions about setting a content/page background in ionic 4, but I did manage to set it, BUT all my experiments also set the `ion-card` background to the content's colour, which is not really what I want. I also tried setting the background colour to the `ion-grid` elem using ids and classes, with the same result.

When I try styling just the `body`, the content's background is not affected at all.

I can probably style the other elements in the content, but I would rather know, what am I missing here in the way the ionic elements are designed to be used, and how to achieve just the background of the page coloured, not the elements on it in the content.

```
ion-content {
    --ion-background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image: The card has a yellow background too.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found with experimenting is that `--ion-background-color:` sets a global background default (which defaults to #fff if not set) for ionic components. To just target ion-content it would be better to set it like `ion-content {--background : #f4a942;}`. You can set an ion-grid background like so `ion-grid {background: #aaa;}`. The issue with the ion card is that by default its background is set to `var(--ion-item-background,transparent)`, so it will use the ion-item-background if one is set or it will be transparent, you can ignore all this by declaring the background with `!important` like `ion-card{--background: #aaa !important;}.`

If you want to find out if the component needs a `--background` or just `background` I've been having to check the ionic docs to see if it has `--background` in its CSS Custom Properties :/